# i want to add url into product Json in shopify liquid product page

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I am new to liquid enviroment i want product json with url key also
i tried some ways but not able to get the destination so can anyone tell me how to assign keys to
objects in liquid

assign master_data = product | json

assign master_data = master_data | url_to_add: product.url

Comment: Already had handle into Json, so why you appending URL own?

Comment: i need it as a key value into product json  thats is why.. im trying to add

Comment: so why you don't use the handle and make URL when using it into liquid or javascript;

Answer (score 0):

You need to try below solution.It's work for  you.

```
{% assign master_data = product | json %}
{% assign modified_data = master_data | append: ',"url":"' | append: product.url | append: '"' %}
```